# How to optimize images with nextjs and S3 aws?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js

So I'm using `nextjs`, `react-hook-form` and `aws` to create a form with images. This is what I have for now:

**form.tsx:**

```
        <Controller
          name={'photoDump'}
          control={control}
          //{...register('photoDump')}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <>
              <FileInputButton field={field} register={register} />
            </>
          )}
        />
```

**FileInput.tsx:**

```
export default function FileInputButton({
  field,
  register,
}: {
  field: any;
  register: any;
}) {
  const inputFileRef: any = useRef(null);
  const updateRef: any = useRef(null);

  async function TransformFileToUrl(file: File, name: string) {
    const { presignedUrl, previewLink, uidKey } =
      await createPresignedUrlWithClient(name);
    console.log('????, ', name, presignedUrl);
    //return { url: `https://fake_url:/${name}`, altText: name };
    console.log(file);
    const result = await fetch(presignedUrl, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: file,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': file.type,
      },
    });

    // console.log('response is : ', result.url);
    // const k = await result.json();
    console.log(`result: for ${name}`, result);
    return { url: presignedUrl, altText: uidKey, previewLink: previewLink };
  }

  async function UpdatePhotoURL(
    file: File,
    presignedUrl: string,
    index: number
  ) {
    const result = await fetch(presignedUrl, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: file,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': file.type,
      },
    });
    console.log(`result: for update`, result);
    //return { url: presignedUrl, altText: uidKey, previewLink: previewLink };
    //field.value[index].altText = file.name;
    const updatedPhoto = {
      ...field.value[index],
      //url: presignedUrl,
      altText: file.name,
    };
    const newValue = [...field.value];
    newValue[index] = updatedPhoto;
    field.onChange(newValue);
  }
  console.log(field);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type='file'
        className='invisible'
        ref={inputFileRef}
        onChange={async (e) => {
          console.log('ON CHANGE TRIGGERED');
          const files = Array.from(e.target.files ?? []);
          const urls = await Promise.all(
            files.map((file) => TransformFileToUrl(file, file.name))
          );

          field.onChange(urls);
        }}
        multiple
        accept='image/*'
      />
      <button type='button' onClick={() => inputFileRef.current.click()}>
        Upload File
      </button>

      {field.value &&
        field.value.length > 0 &&
        field.value.map((photo: any, index: number) => (
          <PreviewCard
            photo={photo}
            updatePhoto={UpdatePhotoURL}
            index={index}
            key={photo.altText}
          />
```

as you can see, when uploading photos at first, I'm creating a presigned URL for PUT requests to update the image. Secondly, the `UpdatePhotoURL` will be used on each PhotoCard as a button to update that single image using the presignedUrl.

**PhotoCard:**

```
const PreviewCard = ({
  photo,
  updatePhoto,
  index,
}: {
  photo: any;
  updatePhoto: any;
  index: number;
}) => {
  const updateRef: any = useRef(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div key={photo.altText}>
      {!isLoading ? (
        <Image
          //key={photo.altText}
          src={`${photo.previewLink}?${new Date().getTime()}`}
          alt={photo.altText}
          width={60}
          height={60}
          //blurDataURL={photo.previewLink}
          //placeholder='blur'
          //loading='lazy'
          //onLoad={() => setIsLoading(false)}
          priority={true}
          onLoad={() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <p> Loading </p>
      )}
      <input
        type='file'
        className='invisible'
        ref={updateRef}
        onChange={async (e) => {
          setIsLoading(true);
          e.target.files &&
            (await updatePhoto(e.target.files[0], photo.url, index));
          //  setIsLoading(false);
        }}
      />

      <button type='button' onClick={() => updateRef.current.click()}>
        {' '}
        UPDATE{' '}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

the logic works, but the photo still flickers after the `isLoading` state is set to `false`
for example, when updating a photo, the `loading` message is shown, then after the image is loaded, it's a blank space for a few milliseconds, then the image is shown. What I intend to do is displaying a message or showing some spinner while the image is loading, to get rid of that flickering until the image is rendered. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep showing a loading indicator until the image is fully loaded, and you seem to be almost there. Here's the revised code of your `PreviewCard` component.

```
const PreviewCard = ({ photo, updatePhoto, index }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div key={photo.altText}>
      {isLoading && <p>Loading...</p>} {/* Show loading indicator */}
      <Image
        src={`${photo.previewLink}?${new Date().getTime()}`}
        alt={photo.altText}
        width={60}
        height={60}
        priority={true}
        onLoad={() => setIsLoading(false)} // Hide loading indicator once image is loaded
        style={{ display: isLoading ? 'none' : 'block' }} // Hide image during load
      />
      <input
        type="file"
        className="invisible"
        onChange={async (e) => {
          setIsLoading(true);
          e.target.files && await updatePhoto(e.target.files[0], photo.url, index);
        }}
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsLoading(true); // Set loading true if you want to indicate loading when UPDATE button is clicked
      }}>
        UPDATE
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```